# Is this actually a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, dupehammer

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26594638/mysql-and-php-login-page-problems) a few minutes ago. A small comment thread was started and an answer posted but then the question was marked as a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18306038/warning-mysql-num-rows-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in).

While the error message is relatively similar, the reason for the message is not. There's more than one way to get the same error message. While the end problem was the same, the fix was different in this case.

It seemed like the dupe hammer was thrown a little prematurely here. What is the communities general consensus?

Comment: The issue does not appear to be `=` vs `==`. Looking at the code, I cannot see any like where the `$sql` variable, which is set to contain an SQL query, is actually passed to a function that executes it. Are my eyes failing? Is there some PHP magic I'm missing? `$result` does not appear to be set either.

Comment: @Louis This is true based on the OP's feedback to _@Cups_ posted answer. I've updated my question to reflect this change. Either way, the duplicate answers point the OP in the right direction but definitely don't address all the issues. There are multiple issues with the OP's code.

Comment: "There are multiple issues with the OP's code." Indeed. The quantity and nature of the problems do not indicate a question that is going to add something valuable to SO. I would not reopen it even if the other question is not a perfect match.

Comment: @Louis That's a completely valid point. Didn't look at it from that stance. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: The question is in danger of being a chameleon question.  Note comments of "Thanks: hasn't fixed the issue though. :( " and the update of code in the [revisions](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26594638/revisions).  The question has a distinct possibility of becoming an interactive debug session.  The original dup was likely right.  The larger problem is that the code isn't about *one* bug and thus isn't an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and can have lots of answers fixing individual problems... that then get an updated question and obsoleted.

Comment: @MichaelT That makes sense. Combined those factors don't make for a very good SO question. I appreciate your feedback.